# $f: M \to N$ be continuous and onto, $M$ compact. Show that $f^{-1}(A)$ closed implies $A$ closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

As stated in the title, for metric spaces $M$ and $N$, I want to show that if the preimage of $A$ is closed in $M$, then $A$ is closed. I already showed the other direction, but this direction is stumping me.

So far I have just written down some basic things. If $y \in N$ is a limit point of $A$, then there exists a sequence $(y_n)\in A\backslash\{y\}$ which converges to $y$ by definition. Also $\forall y_n$ $\exists x_n \in f^{-1}(A)$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$. But now I'm not sure how to use continuity or anything, since it's backwards.

Comment: Which set is compact: $A$ or $N$?

Comment: @carmichael561 Oops sorry, I meant that A is closed in N.

Comment: But aren't you trying to prove that $A$ is closed?

Comment: @carmichael561 Oh my goodness, sorry again!!

Comment: Things are getting confused here because you are referring to the title of your question in the body of your question. Please make the body of your question self-contained and make the title just summarise the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f^{-1}(A)$ is compact because it is a closed set in a compact space. Next, since continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets, $f(f^{-1}(A))$ will be compact. But since $f$ is onto this set is just $A$. So $A$ is compact, hence closed.